# Prevent "new FormData()" in IE from including input elements without a name attribute

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to use jquery ajax to send formData to server...
Here is my html file:

```
 <form id="my_form">
    <div>
        <p>first name :</p>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Bill">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>second name :</p>
        <input type="text" name="second_name" value="Gates">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>should not send to the server :</p>
        <input type="text" value="haha">
    </div>
</form>
```

the first and the second input have the 'name' attribute while the last one do not, since I do not want to send this value to the server.The following is my JS file:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#my_form')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                       method : 'POST',
                       url :'/api/requestUrl',
                       data : formData,
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       success : function() {
                        ...
                           }
                       },
                   });
```

Here comes my question,When I run this in IE11, the Request Payload likes the following picture[Request Payload in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kemTw.png), and the server says it is a bad content body, so the request failed:

And If I run this in Chrome, it works well,the Request Payload is :
[Request Payload in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0bKR.png) 
I know that if I remove the last input which does not have the 'name' attribute from the Dom, it will work even in IE, So, is there a way to make it work in IE if I remain the last input? thanks a lot...

Comment: Uhhm, I don't think IE should be doing that (because it seems so .. off). Is IE running as native IE11 or is it under emulation? Also, is that the native FormData or a custom?

Comment: @user2864740 It is running as native IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is indeed an IE bug. One quick workaround is to disable the unnamed input before creating the `FormData` object.

```
var $form = $("#my_form");

// Disable "input" elements (input, select, textarea) that do not have 
// a name attribute and were not disabled beforehand, saving a reference to them
var $unnamedInputs = $form.find(":input:not([name]):not(:disabled)").prop('disabled', true);

var formData = new FormData($form[0]);

// Re-enable the inputs that we had just disabled
$unnamedInputs.prop('disabled', false);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/31psrtwm/2/)

[image: Request body in IE11]

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the original `form`, remove last `input` element or `input` element that does not have `name` attribute, then set `FormData` parameter to cloned `form` where last `input` would not be included.

```
var clone = $("#my_form").clone();
clone.find("input:last").remove();
var formData = new FormData(clone[0]);
```